# Save computation time with mgcv?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, basis-function

Suppose we have a generalized additive model that is formulated as

```
gam(y~s(x,bs='tp',k=10),...)
```

I need to repeat the computation many times (e.g., 1000) for the same `x` but with different `y`. I would like to save the overhead setup time, so is there a mechanism with `gam` to obtain the basis functions, the model matrix and the penalty matrix once through eigen-decomposition in the case of thin plat splines, and then just directly feed them into `s()` somehow to all the other models?

Comment: Just wanting to confirm; you have multivariate $\boldsymbol{Y}$, where each column vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ is an observation of some variable at the same set of locations as the other response *and* the covariates? I.e. you have multiple response variable on the same set of observational units as the covariates, no missing values (or these have been dealt with before we get anywhere near fitting a GAM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the things I wrote in my comment on your question hold, then yes, I believe you can do this using the `fit = FALSE` in the call to `gam()`, and then modify the object returned to replace the response data, and then pass this object to `gam()` as argument `G`.

Here's an example:

```r
## packages
library('mgcv')
library('gratia')
library('dplyr')

## simulate some data
set.seed(2)
N <- 400
SCALE <- 2
# Gu Wabha four term additive model
dat <- data_sim('eg1', n = N, scale = SCALE)

## fit a model as normal for comparison
b <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3),
         data = dat, method = 'REML')

## Re do what we just did but this time don't fit
G <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3),
         fit = FALSE, # <--- Not fitting
         data = dat, method = 'REML')

## simulate some new y given the original covariate values
## reusing some internal functions from gratia to evaluate
## the four functions of Gu & Wabha at the origin Xs
set.seed(1)
dat <- mutate(dat,
              y2 = gratia:::gw_f0(x0) + gratia:::gw_f1(x1) +
                  gratia:::gw_f2(x2) + gratia:::gw_f3(x3) +
                  rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = SCALE))

## update the components of the model that appear to be
##  related to `y`
G$y <- G$mf$y <- dat$y2

## fit the model with new y
b2 <- gam(G = G)
```

This is the fit of the first model with the original `y`

[image]

and this is the fit with the second sample of response data

[image]

and the output from the models is slightly different, as it should be here as we simulated the same structural form for the second response but we added new Gaussian noise:

```r
summary(b)
```

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.83328    0.09872   79.35   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(x0) 3.021  3.753  6.234 0.000129 ***
s(x1) 2.843  3.529 69.711  < 2e-16 ***
s(x2) 8.020  8.741 86.424  < 2e-16 ***
s(x3) 1.001  1.003  4.244 0.040015 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.716   Deviance explained = 72.6%
-REML = 861.13  Scale est. = 3.898     n = 400
```

and for the model with the updated `y`

```r
summary(b2)
```

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7.8718     0.0967    81.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df       F  p-value    
s(x0) 3.027  3.759  13.690 9.95e-10 ***
s(x1) 3.778  4.662  79.603  < 2e-16 ***
s(x2) 7.463  8.412 101.660  < 2e-16 ***
s(x3) 1.000  1.000   0.003     0.96    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.763   Deviance explained = 77.2%
GCV = 3.8992  Scale est. = 3.7406    n = 400
```

You will see different behaviour if you various response are different things; here I wanted to check that I had found all the places where `y` was stored and replaced them all so I should get essentially the same fits here.

Comment: You're the wonderful guru! I didn't realize the existence of `G` in `gam`.

Comment: No similar trick exists for `gamm` and `gamm4`?